# VBA in PowerPoint: ColorIndex to change textcolor?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm copy pasting data from Excel into a PowerPoint presentation using VBA. Now I have added a textbox and want to change the color of the text within it. It works when using "vbBlack" or RGB

```
myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = vbBlack

myPresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

However, can I use ColorIndex for this? When I try it says it doesn't recognize the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powerpoint does not include the `ColorIndex` property in the [`ColorFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.colorformat).  However, it does include the [`ColorConstants` enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/color-constants).

You can also use [`SchemeColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.colorformat.schemecolor) or [`ObjectThemeColor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.colorformat.objectthemecolor)

You would need to set a cell to `ColorIndex`, and then retrieve the `Color` to get the RGB value.